# SHAP explainer for a sequential model with 3D input and 3D output

Tags: python, tensorflow, shap

I have a sequential binary classification model in Keras (Tensorflow 2.2.0) which takes the input of shape (n_samples, n_timesteps, n_features) and provides the output of shape (n_samples, n_timesteps, 1). I'm trying to use [SHAP GradientExplainer](https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#gradient-explainer) with this model.

I followed their examples this way:

```
 import shap
 explainer = shap.GradientExplainer(Seq_Model, X_train_3D[:10])
 shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_test_3D[:3])
```

but I get this error:

`AssertionError: The model output must be a vector or a single value!`

Now, I'm looking for a way to use SHAP GradientExplainer (or any other type of SHAP explainers that works with this TF version) that provides insights for models with 3D output. Any help is appreciated.